# Is there a way to solve json file parsing errors while installing a npm package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I was trying to install the angular cli and create-react-app with npm in the node.js command prompt but I get this error both times : "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."rx":"^2.3.25","serve'"

I've tried to re-install node.js and update npm to the last version, hoping it will fix the file but i still have the error

So do you have any idea about how to fix this and to be able to install what I need correctly ?

Comment: Share your package.json file

Comment: Copy all of your project to another folder,without node_modules , then go in your new folder and run cmd, and try npm install ,maybe it works

Comment: Looks like a syntax error in your package.json.